# Designing an Algorithm to find the length of a simple cycle in a d-regular graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-traversal

[image]

I understand the question in general but don't know how to design and analyze the algorithm in the question. I was thinking of applying some sort of graph search algorithm like depth-first / breadth-first search.

UPDATE: This is what I have tried, starting from any Node of the graph (call it N), visit each of that node's d neighbors. Now, the last neighbor we just visited of N (call it L) visit any other neighbor of L that is not N ?

Comment: I would start with adding a link to what is a regular graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph). Also, what have you tried? What happens if you start from a node and randomly start "walking" over the graph? Why won't that work - and how do you fix it?

Comment: Here are some ideas that might be (indirectly) helpful: There can be at most n(n-1)/2 edges in a component, and at most n-1 edges in a forest (collection of trees).  In a d-regular graph, we can think of every vertex "contributing" d/2 edges to the total (since each edge is incident on 2 vertices).

Comment: What is a simple cycle of `N` length? It is a list of nodes, containing `N` entries. Because it's a cycle, the first and the last node is the same. Because it'is a simple cycle, all the nodes in between are different from the first and each other. So you need to find routes  `N-1` long, where the nodes are all different, and then there is a connection from the last node to the first, closing the cycle.

Comment: @biziclop I've thought about it for several minutes now I still can't come up with a solution. I understand what you mean by simply cycle.

Comment: I would probably start with something simple, like `d=1`. In that case the problem degenerates into finding any cycle. So what happens when `d=2`?

Comment: @biziclop: I think the question is asking the OP to come up with some algorithm that exploits the d-regular structure to do better than the brute-force algorithm you suggest in your first comment.  E.g. for d=1, there can't be any cycles; for d=2, there can be *only* (disjoint) cycles.

Comment: Having thought about this a bit more, the algorithm is actually in many ways quite simple (and also fast to run) -- but the steps involved in proving that it always works are tricky!  Hint: There are 2 phases.  In the first phase, you find a path of length n+1 (you need to prove that the algorithm can always do this (subhint: backtracking isn't necessary)); in the second phase, you keep extending this path while you must (this involves proving that you can always do *either* one of two things, and that this process terminates).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, I only meant that as a starting point, pencil and paper style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already hinted on a possible solution in comments, let's elaborate. When `d<=1`, the solutions are immediate (and depend on your exact definition of cycle), so I'll assume `d>1`.

One such algorithm would be:

1. Build a path starting in any vertex `V`. Until the path has length `d`, don't allow vertices you've already visited.
2. Once the path is `d` vertices long, keep adding vertices to the path, but now only allow vertices different from the last `d` vertices of the path.
3. When you add a vertex that's already been used in the path, stop. You create the resulting cycle from a segment of the path starting and ending in that vertex.

In both (1) and (2), the existence of such a vertex is guaranteed by the fact that G is d-regular. When searching for the vertex to add, we only exclude the last `d` vertices, namely the last vertex (`U`) and its `d-1` predecessors. U has `d` neighbors, so at least one of them has to be available.

The algorithm will stop, because of the condition (3) and the fact that G is finite.

It makes sense to prefer already visited vertices in (2), but it doesn't change the worst-case complexity.

This gives us the worst-case complexity of `n*d` - for we may have to visit once every vertex and check all of its edges.